# Use ORDER BY 'x' with a JOIN, but keep rows that don't have a value for 'x'

Tags: mysql, optimization

This is simplified version of a relatively complex problem that myself and my colleagues can't quite get our heads around.

Consider two tables, `table_a` and `table_b`. In our CMS `table_a` holds metadata for all the data stored in the database, and `table_b` has some more specific information, so for simplicity's sake, a `title` and `date` column.

At the moment our query looks like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_a` LEFT OUTER JOIN `table_b` ON (table_a.id = table_b.id)
WHERE table_a.col = 'value'
ORDER BY table_b.date ASC
LIMIT 0,20
```

This degrades badly when `table_a` has a large amount of rows. If the JOIN is changed `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` (which triggers MySQL to use the INDEX set on `table_b.date`), the query is infinitely quicker, but it doesn't produce the same results (because if `table_b.date` doesn't have a value, it is ignored).

This becomes an issue in our CMS because if the user sorts on the date column, any rows that don't have a date set yet disappear from the interface, creating a confusing UI experience and makes it difficult to add dates for the rows that missing them.

Is there a solution that will:

1. Use `table_b`.date's INDEX so that
   the query will scale better
2. Somehow retain those rows in
   `table_b` that don't have a `date`
   set so that a user can enter the
   data

Comment: you can do a right join plus a union...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to second ArtoAle's comment.  since the `order by` applies to a null value in the outer join for missing rows in `table_b`, those rows will be out of order anyway.

The simulated outer join is the ugly part, so lets look at that first.  Mysql doesn't have `except`, so you need to write the query in terms of `exists`.

```
SELECT table_a.col1, table_a.col2, table_a.col3, ... NULL as table_b_col1, NULL as ...
FROM
    table_a
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_a INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id);
```

Which should be `UNION ALL`ed with the original query as an inner join.  The `UNION_ALL` is needed to preserve the original order.

This sort of query is probably going to be dog-slow no matter what you do, because there won't be an index that readily supports a "Foreign Key not present" sort of query.  This basically boils down to an index scan in table_a.id with a lookup (Or maybe a parallel scan) for the corresponding row in table_b.id.

Answer (score 0):

So we ended up implemented a different solution that while the results were not as good as using an INDEX, it still provided a nice speed boost of around 25%.

We remove the JOIN and instead used an ORDER BY subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_a`
WHERE table_a.col = 'value'
ORDER BY (
   SELECT date 
   FROM table_b 
   WHERE id = table_a.id
) ASC
LIMIT 0,20
```